# Send "Email with image" from struts2 application. How to access the image location in Action class

Tags: image, url, struts2, jakarta-mail

Iam on a Struts application!

I  have a image in the folder at the root of the application. i.e.,

```
ApplicationName--> webContent --> images-->logo.jpg
```

Iam sending a mail using javamail . I want to use the image to create the body of the email.

Iam using the multipart able to send the mail perfectly without image Image .
But dont know how to achieve the mail with the logo.jpg image in the body ~

Please can someone specify how to :

1. access the image from action to send attach it to the email.

Please some one help me out !

Comment: Pls mention what you have tried from the Action class to access the image or any error?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

just do this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
String imgPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/path/to/your/img");
File img = new File(imgPath);
```

Then you get the img file. `/path/to/your/img` should be the relative path to your img. in this case, it should be `/images/logo.jpg`

Comment: After this code the img variable contains the image and then he has to find a way to figure out to send the image in the java mail.Is it correct?

Comment: @PratapMurukutla sure, this is another question, but you can get 1000+ tutorials to do this. here is an example: http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/javamail_sending_embedded_image_in

Comment: You could also create an action which displays the picture and then simply create an html message (you can then track who looked at the picture if they have unique names and thus know if the mail was read... well to a degree)

Comment: Hi Thanks !Now iam able to get the Url of the image !

Comment: But the image is showing as a attachment in the mail But not as as embeded image ! May be the problem with the "cid ". Please can  you specify how to clear this

Comment: @deepuginde if you wanna embed the image, you should use HTML Format, which means you build a `<img />` tag in your email. check this link:http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-embed-images-in-html-mail-using-javamail